# Display firebase data in List

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

Working on grabbing my data from Firebase, then displaying the results to a list. Currently I am attempting to map each document to a model, then displaying in it a list.

I believe the issues are stemming from my recipeLogic class, but any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Logic Class

```
class RecipeLogic: ObservableObject {
   
    @Published var recipes = [RecipeItems]()
    @Published var recipeList: [RecipeItems] = []
  
    init(){
     grabRecipes()
    }
    
    private func grabRecipes(){
        guard let uid = FirebaseManager.shared.auth.currentUser?.uid else {
            return
        }
        
        FirebaseManager.shared.firestore
            .collection("users")
            .document(uid)
            .collection("userRecipes")
            .addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, err) in
                guard let querySnapshot = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                    print("no docs")
                    return
                    }
                self.recipes = querySnapshot.map {snapshot -> RecipeItems in
                    let data = snapshot.data()
                    let recipeTitle = data ["recipeTitle"] as? String ?? ""
                    let recipePrepTime = data ["recipePrepTime"] as? String ?? ""
                    let recipeImage = data ["recipeImage"] as? String ?? ""
                    let createdAt = data ["createdAt"] as? String ?? ""
                    let ingredients = data ["ingredientItem"] as? [String] ?? [""]
                    let directions = data ["directions"] as? [String] ?? [""]
                    
                    return RecipeItems(recipeTitle: recipeTitle, recipePrepTime: recipePrepTime, recipeImage: recipeImage, createdAt: createdAt, directions: directions, ingredientItem: ingredients)
                }
            }
        print(recipes)
        }
    }
```

List View

```
struct RecipeListView: View {
    @ObservedObject var rm = RecipeLogic()
    @State var listofRecipes: [RecipeListModel] = RecipeList.recipes
    @State var recipeViewToggle = false
  
    init(){
        UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            List{
                ForEach(rm.recipes, id: \.self ){ recipe in
                        HStack{
                            Image("")
                                .resizable()
                               .frame (width: 70, height:70)
                                .cornerRadius(15)
                            VStack{
                                ZStack{
                                    Text("")
                                        .font(.body)
                                    //temp solution until I can center it
                                        .padding(.top, 1)
                                    //as a note, sets empty view to hide list arrow
                                    NavigationLink(destination: {RecipeController(name: "tim", image: "")}, label: {
                                        emptyview()
                                        })
                                        .opacity(0.0)
                                        .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                                    
                                    Text("10g 25g 88g")
                                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                                        .padding(.top, 80)
                                        .padding(.bottom, 10)
                                        .padding(.trailing, 10)
                                        .frame(height:90)
                                }
                                .padding(.top, -20)
            
                                }
                            .padding(EdgeInsets(top: -5, leading: -25, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
                            }
                        }
                
                .onAppear {
                    
                    //sets recipe to only show 3 recipes
                    if listofRecipes.count > 3 {
                        listofRecipes = listofRecipes.dropLast(listofRecipes.count - 3)
                    }
                   }
                ZStack{
                    NavigationLink(destination:RecipeFullListView()) {
                           emptyview()
                       }
                    .opacity(0.0)
                    .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                       HStack {
                           Text("View More")
                               .font(.body)
                               .frame(width:300)
                               .padding(.top, 20)
                       }
                }
            }
           
        }
    
    }
}
```

Model Class

```
struct RecipeItems: Hashable{
    var recipeTitle, recipePrepTime, recipeImage, createdAt: String
    var directions, ingredientItem: [String]
}

struct RecipeModel{
   var id: String = UUID().uuidString
    var recipes: [RecipeItems]
}
```

I'll also attach a screenshot of my Firebase setup as well
[image]

Comment: I think you are comfusing yourself due to the bad naming of variables and
 duplications of the arrays. My advice is, rename for example, `RecipeLogic` to `RecipesModel`,
 `RecipeItems` to `RecipeItem`, get rid of `RecipeListModel`, and
 `@Published var recipeList:...`, just keep only one source of truth
 `@Published var recipes = [RecipeItem]()`. In `RecipeListView`, use the new
 `@StateObject var rm = RecipesModel()`, get rid of `listofRecipes`.
 Make `struct RecipeItem: Identifiable, Hashable { let id = UUID() ....`.

Comment: You don't know how much I appreciate that...By cleaning up the variables, setting up the struct, I was able to get it working. Thank you !

Comment: great news, glad I could help.